# How to use numpy linspace on multiple lines in dataset

Tags: python, numpy, linspace

Hello I need to use linspace to create points between two rows at a time in a dataset.

```
'location'
 1
 10
 12
 14
```

Essentially use linspace to find points between rows 1 & 2(1,10), then 3 & 4(12,14) (...for hundreds of rows). Any advice would be really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of locations, you could just iterate over the list in steps of two:

```
import numpy as np

# List of locations
locs = [1, 10, 12, 14] # …possibly more

# List for storing linspace output
lins = list()

# Iterate over the locations list in steps of two
for i in range(0, len(locs), 2):
    lins.append(np.linspace(locs[i], locs[i+1]))
```

Note that this solution only works if the number of elements in the `locations` list is even. If the number of elements is odd you'll need to modify the for loop; something like:

`for i in range(0, len(locs)-1, 2):`

Since you're asking about computing the linspace between pairs of elements, your last element would have no paired element anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```py
>>> rows = [1, 10, 12, 14]
>>> n_points = 5
>>> for i in range(0, len(rows)//2*2, 2):
        print(np.linspace(*rows[i:i+2], n_points))
[ 1.    3.25  5.5   7.75 10.  ]
[12.  12.5 13.  13.5 14. ]
```